# Horizontal UIStackView with two label (one multiline label, one one-line)

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview

I have a horizontal `UIStackView` which has two `UILabel` in it. First UILabel is multiline (two line) and other one is one line only. They both have default content compression and resistance priorities. **My problem** is that even there is a gap between labels, "best" word in first text goes second line. I noticed that first label doesn't goes beyond half of total width.

**What I want** is that second label should always show itself and first label should size It self for remaining space. If It can't fit to one line It should be two line. However, If second label is too short and first label is a long one but both of them can fit, first label should go beyond half of the width.

**P.S** I need to use UIStackView in this scenario because there are other cases. I know putting two label inside UIView may solve the problem.

```
UIStackView:
   - Distribution: Horizontal
   - Alignment: Center
   - Spacing: 0
   UILabel:
     - Number of line: 2
     - Line break: Word wrap
   UILabel:
     - Number of line: 1
```

[image: Screenshot]

View hierarchy:

[image]

**Desired Result:**

[image]

**OR**

[image]

**EDIT:** I calculate the width of second label and give width constraint. I think It solved my problem, I'll test a bit.

```
        //Give specific width to second label to make first one calculate right number of lines.
    if let font = UIFont(name: "Metropolis-ExtraBold", size: 15) {
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = (secondLabelText as NSString).size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
        secondLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
    }
```

Comment: How much is the spacing that you've provided for this stack view? Try decreasing it. And you don't need a stack view for adjusting two labels. Autolayout can help you out with this kind of implementation.

Comment: Can you show us your desired state ?

Comment: I edited my question @MojtabaHosseini

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To try and simplify...

Forget calculating any widths... what matters is the horizontal `Content Hugging` and `Content Compression Resistance`

Leave the left (blue) label at the defaults:

```
Content Hugging Priority
    Horizontal: 251

Content Compression Resistance Priority:
    Horizontal: 750
```

But set the right (orange) label to:

```
Content Hugging Priority
    Horizontal: 1000

Content Compression Resistance Priority:
    Horizontal: 1000
```

Results:

[image]

The only other issue would be if the text in the right-side label exceeds the full width of the view -- but you haven't indicated that you might need that much text.

Answer (score 1):

You should set different horizontal **content compression resistant**s for each of them:

[image: Multiple values]

For this case, the blue one(multiline) should have something less than the orange one(Singleline).

<sub>Assistive note: Multiline: 250, Singleline: 750</sub>

Orange Settings:
[image: Orange Settings]

Blue Settings:
[image: OrangeSettings]

**Note that** I have set the line limit of the orange one to `0`. You can set it to anything you like. But if you like to make it selfsize to **anyhight** taller view should have higher **vertical compression resistant** than 250.

Comment: Sorry I can't open Imgur, can you please write me the values?

Comment: No problem, I have updated the answer with values. Note that my colors doesn't match with your colors.

Answer (score 0):

First embed your multiline label inside a view and constraint the label to this view (top, leading, trailing, bottom). After that add your view with your multiline label and single line label to your stackView.

Then you can use .fillProportionally for the distribution of your UIStackView and the spacing value to specify the space between your two labels.

Make also sure to use Required (1000) for your horizontal content compression resistance priority on your right number label.

View-hierarchy:

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]

With spacing between your labels:

[image]

Comment: If I use fillEqually, firstLabel will be half of the width which is happening right now and I don't want it because second label can be so short the there can be enough space for first label

Comment: When I do fillProportionally, first label disappear.

Comment: In my answer you are still using UIStackView to perform the auto layout part. You are just embedding the multiline label inside your stackview inside another view.

Comment: When I do it like that, second label lost Its priority which means that It showed like "113123342..." when It doesn't fit.

Comment: Just use Required (1000) for your horizontal content compression resistance priority on your number label and you will be finde